# Symfony Form Testing member function create() on null

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, codeception

I'm trying to test my form. I read that :

But I get a `null` exception

```
class MediaTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {

    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function testMe()
    {

        $formData = array(
            'test' => 'test',
            'test2' => 'test2',
        );

        $form = $this->factory->create(MediaType::class);

        // submit the data to the form directly
        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals(new Media(), $form->getData());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that the line buggy is :

> $form = $this->factory->create(MediaType::class);

But how can I resolve ?

I launch :

> phpunit tests/unit/Form/MediaTypeTest.php

Or via codeception :

> php vendor/bin/codecept run unit Form/MediaTypeTest.php

Any idea ?

Comment: check you are extending the right class: `Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase instead` of `Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\Extension\Validator\Type\TypeTestCase`. Let me know

Answer (score 3):

The factory object is [initializated in the setup method of the parent test class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Test/FormIntegrationTestCase.php#L29) so You should call the `parent` in the `setup` method of your testCase **(or remove the empty implementation of it)**.

So in general remember to call the parent class method when you override the inherit method:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
}

protected function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

Hope this help